# Configure mybatis to use an existing connection

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, blackboard

I want to set up a connection between my application and a Oracle database. I do not have the following database information:

1. URL
2. user name
3. password

What I can retrieve is a valid `java.sql.Connection` by using the API provided by Blackboard.

Is it possible to set up mybatis in this case?

I am using the configuration shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" 
 "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>

    <settings>
        <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="true"/>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL"/>
    </settings>

    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="assignment" type="simpleproj.assignment.model.Assignment"/>
        <typeAlias alias="assignmentLog" type="simpleproj.assignment.model.AssignmentLog"/>
    </typeAliases>

    <mappers>   
        <mapper resource="simpleproj/assignment/model/Assignment.xml" />
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

This is how I get a new `SqlSessionFactory` instance:

```
String resource = "mybatis-config.xml";
Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
return new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, "assignment");
```

Afterwards, I try to retrieve a session by this code:

```
session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(connection);
```

I have checked that the `connection` is valid with:

1. `connection.isValid(3);`, which returns true
2. a `PreparedStatement` can be executed successfully

However, `sqlSessionFactory.openSession(connection)` generates errors with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error opening session.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
### Cause: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromConnection(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSession(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:67)
        at simpleproj.assignment.dao.DatabaseDAO.getSession(DatabaseDAO.java:55)
        at simpleproj.assignment.dao.DatabaseDAO.deleteAssignmentList(DatabaseDAO.java:124)
        at simpleproj.assignment.AssignmentLoader.importData(AssignmentLoader.java:85)
        at simpleproj.assignment.AssignmentLoader.main(AssignmentLoader.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at $Proxy7.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromConnection(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:99)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at blackboard.db.ConnectionManager$ConnectionProxy.invoke(ConnectionManager.java:1419)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@1627c16 is closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.checkOpen(DelegatingConnection.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.getAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:337)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

From this error:oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@1627c16 is closed.
This connection is closed when you passed it to sqlSessionFactoryBean.
You can call connection.getAutoCommit() to test the connection whether it support transaction.

Comment: Tested with `connection.getAutoCommit()`, but this line throws the same exception `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException at $Proxy7.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)`.