# Creating thread safe MyBatis sessions from a java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mybatis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use MyBatis with a Snowflake database.  My situation is similar to that of this poster:

[Configure mybatis to use an existing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295170/configure-mybatis-to-use-an-existing-connection)

Essentially, I can get a java.sql.Connection Object, but I cannot get that by way of a DataSource, or other steps normally done by RDBMS databases like Oracle.  One proposed solution is to do something like
this:

```
SqlSession snowflakeSession = snowflakeSqlSessionFactory.openSession(getSnowflakeConnection());
```

These will be in a multi-threaded environment.  If someone closes the snowflakeSession object, does that close the underlying java.sql.Connection object?  I plan to re-use these sessions, but only within a thread.  Is this necessary?

For Oracle, I can do this:

```
        OracleDataSource result = new OracleDataSource();
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String connectionString = jdbcUrl;
        String username = jdbcUserName; 
        String password = jdbcPassword;
        OracleDataSource oracleDataSource = (OracleDataSource)result; 
        oracleDataSource.setURL(connectionString);
        oracleDataSource.setPassword(password);
        oracleDataSource.setUser(username);
        String timeoutKey = "oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout";
        Properties connectionProperties;
        try {
            connectionProperties = oracleDataSource.getConnectionProperties();
            if(connectionProperties==null) {
                connectionProperties = new Properties();
            }
            connectionProperties.put(timeoutKey, 60 /* minutes */ * 60 /* seconds per minutes */ * 1000 /* ms per seconds */);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
```

If I could create say a SnowflakeDataSource object, I could easily create the connection in the same way as I do for Oracle.  I have to be careful how to create the connection because it's also the same point that MyBatis scans the XML mapper files, or re-uses what it already found from a previous connection request.

Comment: Why can't you use a `DataSource`? If you can create JDBC connections, you can use a `DataSource` (or implement your own).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm editing my question to show my approach for Oracle, which I can't find for Snowflake

Comment: You don't need to use a Snowflake specific `DataSource`, you can use - for example - HikariCP, and get connection pooling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear [to be documented](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html) but the Snowflake's JDBC Driver package does offer a [basic DataSource class](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/5339cfb4531457fb9904b61eaaafcfba01b97c1a/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeBasicDataSource.java#L24) that can fetch entirely [new connection objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62641174/13472370) when `DataSource::getConnection()` is called:

```java
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBasicDataSource;

SnowflakeBasicDataSource ds = new SnowflakeBasicDataSource();

ds.setUrl("jdbc:snowflake://account.region.snowflakecomputing.com/");

ds.setUser("user");
ds.setPassword("password");
ds.setWarehouse("wh");
ds.setDatabaseName("db");
ds.setSchema("schema");
ds.setRole("role");

// Other arbitrary connection or session properties can be passed
// via URL params in the ds.setUrl(...) call above

// Use ds.setOauthToken(...)
// or  ds.setAuthenticator(...)
// or  ds.setPrivateKey(...)
// or  ds.setPrivateKeyFile(...)
// for alternative modes of authentication

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```